# android save image in sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I wrote code witch can to save image to sd card.my code working perfect but when i going to sd car with file system my image is public.this is my code

```
private Bitmap takeScreenShot(Context content, ScrollView view) {

    int totalHeight = view.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int totalWidth = view.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(view, totalHeight, totalWidth);


    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/image.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(content.getContentResolver(),
                bitmap, "Screen", "screen");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;

}
```

how i can save imege in sd card to can hide or unpublish my image.i meean ,i don't need to can show it with file manager
if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Use `getFilesDir()` instead.

Comment: There is no chance to save image to SD card and hide it from user. You can remove file extension (*.jpg) to make it potentionally unreadable for phone applications. Second approach -> encoding. Depends on level of privacy you want to achieve.